# ParseQuery can't find any items in date searching

Tags: java, android, date, parse-platform, datepicker

I'm working with parse (yeah I know it's soon to be dead but this project will be dead soon either so it doesn't matter) and I'm using ParseQuery.

My program records work shifts, which are recorded bu start hour and end hour, both of those are dates.

In this problem, I want to filter the shift records shower by a starting date and an ending date, both are inputted by datePickerDialog, but even through there should be some shifts found in the query, nothing has been found. I've checked the dates, both inputted and saved in parse, but there is something I'm missing. any help please?

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener1= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        yearf=year;
        monthf=monthOfYear+1;
        dayf=dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(ShiftfilterActivity.this, dayf+"/"+monthf+"/"+yearf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvFrom.setText(dayf + "/" + monthf + "/" + yearf);
        d1.setDate(dayf);
        d1.setMonth(monthf);
        d1.setYear(yearf);
    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener2= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        yeart=year;
        montht=monthOfYear+1;
        dayt=dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(ShiftfilterActivity.this, dayt+"/"+montht+"/"+yeart, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvTo.setText(dayt + "/" + montht + "/" + yeart);
        d2.setDate(dayt);
        d2.setMonth(montht);
        d2.setYear(yeart);
        int x = d2.compareTo(d1);
        Toast.makeText(ShiftfilterActivity.this,String.valueOf(x) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(btnShow==v)
     {
         ParseQuery q = new ParseQuery("shiftRecords");
         q.whereGreaterThan("startHour",d1);
         q.whereLessThan("startHour", d2);
         q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
             @Override
             public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {


                 Toast.makeText(ShiftfilterActivity.this,"d1=" + d1.getYear() + " d2=" + d2.getYear() + "list=" + list.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 lvFilteredShifts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 shiftAdapter=new ShiftAdapter(ShiftfilterActivity.this,0,0,list);
                 lvFilteredShifts.setAdapter(shiftAdapter);
             }
         });


     }

}
```

**thanks in advance!**